# SLD intervals with greater than 255 classes

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I am trying to style a raster in GeoServer using a SLD file. I have 850 individual values, but only 179 color mappings (i.e., unique RGBA codes). I want to keep all 850 values, as they are meaningful, but the SLD file fails to style with more than 255 color mappings (even if < 255 distinct colors are used).

Is there a way in which I can maintain all 850 values and still style the raster with the SLD?

The work around I can see would be to create a "styling raster" that reclasses each of the 850 values to a color-mapping indicator, but this is less than desirable due to the loss of meaningful information and the redundant raster layer.

Example code to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about:

```
<ColorMap>
  ...
  <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#eeb241" quantity="255" label="255th value"/>
  <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#eeb241" quantity="256" label="256th value"/>
  ... 
</ColorMap>
```

The styling from the SLD fails here. Note that the colors are the same in the above two lines (e.g., unique color number 179), but the quantities have exceeded 255.

### Edit 1

The quantity to color mappings unfortunately are not organized logically, and thus I am unsure that an `extended` `intervals` type SLD will do the trick. The `ColorMapEntry`s look more like:

```
<ColorMap type="intervals">
  <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" quantity="3001" label="1st value"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" quantity="3002" label="2nd value"/>
  <ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="3003" label="3rd value"/>
  ... other values ...
  <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" quantity="3089" label="89th value"/>
  ...
</ColorMap>
```

So, there you can see that white is being mapped to many values, but the quantities are not organized in a logical fashion that groups the color mapping together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to colour adjacent values with the same colour you could use the [interval option](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html) to `ColorMap` as you only have 179 colours to apply. This colours all the values between the intervals the colour in the lower `ColorMapEntry` until they equal or exceed the next entry.

```
<ColorMap type="intervals" extended="true">
    <ColorMapEntry color="#EEBE2F" quantity="-300" label="label" opacity="0"/>
    ...
    <ColorMapEntry color="#DDB02C" quantity="600" label="label" opacity="1"/>
```

Comment: This is useful, but I don't think will quite achieve what I want. Unfortunately the 179 colors are not organized in a logical fashion -- i.e., they are not grouped together but are rather dispersed throughout the dataset randomly by quantity. I've edited my question to better convey this. Do you know of a way to deal with this?